# react-admin save data from custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-admin

I am new to JS and React.

My Goal is to populate custom Edit containing react-seat-picker with data with current record in a react-admin List. Then I choose a seat and I want to save the new seat selection via the default Save button?

I am using react admin trying to integrate react-seat-picker into custom create form. I managed to bring into react-seat-map values from database via react-admin but when I save
no change happens. In console I see that there is an UPDATE fired when pushing SAVE button but it always contains same data object that was populated in query.

```js
export const SeatEdit = (props) => (
      <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
          < SeatInput /> 
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
```

then I have this custom functional component:

```js
const SeatInput = ({ record }) => {    
    ......
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({ 
         type: 'getOne', 
         resource: 'Seats',
         payload: { id: record.id }
    });

    if (loading) return <Loading />;
    if (error) return ('error');
    if (!data) return null;

    ....
```

then I access data using data.id, data.seat, etc. I populate the graphical seat map, user can click on seat to choose it and then I want that seat selection updated in  my database with a boolean flag isReserved.

When I click on default Save button of Create View I see in browser console log that an update is fired but it contains initial data object that I got back from the query although I assign different values into it during functional component call.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use `useInput` function in `react-admin` for InputField

Here is the example component with `react-select`

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Labeled, useInput } from 'react-admin'
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

const SelectAsync = props => {
  const {
    input: { name, onChange, value },
    meta: { touched, error },
    isRequired
  } = useInput(props);

  const customOnChange = (option, type) => {
    if (type.action === "select-option") {
      onChange(option.value)
    }
  }

  return <Labeled label={props.label} fullWidth>
    <AsyncSelect {...props}
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={customOnChange}
      error={!!(touched && error)}
      helperText={touched && error}
      required={isRequired}
    />
  </Labeled>
};

export default SelectAsync
```